# dumb xml-file with unique tags (Java)

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I have a .xml file with this kind of tag: "tag_X" and "sub_tagY". Like this:

```
<tag_1>
  <sub_tag1>
    <key>something here</key>
  </sub_tag1>
<tag_1>
<tag_2>
  <sub_tag1>
    <key>something here</key>
  </sub_tag1>
  <sub_tag2>
    <key>something here</key>
  </sub_tag2>
<tag_2>
<tag_3>
  <sub_tag1>
    <key>something here</key>
  </sub_tag1>
<tag_3>
```

I started using DOM but this is not working properly...
Can anyone help me to read it in Java? Thanks!!

Comment: please show what you have got in the program. (code)

Comment: what you have tried? post the source code? Do not expect full source code.try yourself or at least post your source code?

Comment: [See here for reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140614/xml-parsing-with-child-not-value-parsing/12141225#12141225)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xstream` library. More details about [XStream Docs](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)

Thanks