# Parsing Different Structured XML in Java using Dom Parser?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse XML data using Dom Parser in Java.

I am successful to parse the following XML Data -

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I have used the code from [**HERE**](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/).

But when I am trying to parse the following XML data -

```
<body message="hello">
<mainData data1="XYZ" data2="ABC" data3="PQR"></mainData>
</body>
```

It is giving null pointer exception.

Both XML have different structure, the first one is common, but the second I dont know about it.

Please help me to parse the XML in second structure using Java.

My code is -

```
try

{
    String strUrl = "http://someurl";
    URL url = new URL(strUrl);
    InputStream inStream = url.openStream();

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inStream);

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("body");

    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) 
    {
           Node nNode = nList.item(i);
           if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
           {
              Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

              NodeList nListRoute = eElement.getElementsByTagName("mainData");
              for (int j = 0; j < nListRoute.getLength(); j++)
              {
                   Node nNodeRoute = nListRoute.item(j);
                   if (nNodeRoute.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                   {
                      Element eElementRoute = (Element) nNodeRoute;

                      NodeList nlList = eElementRoute.getElementsByTagName("data1").item(0).getChildNodes();
                      Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
                      System.out.println("data1 : " + nValue.getNodeValue());
                  }                        
             }                           
          }                
    }           
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I am getting the error -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

On the line "***NodeList nlList = eElementRoute.getElementsByTagName("data1").item(0).getChildNodes();***"

Comment: Both seem to valid XML. Where does your exception occur?

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried and show a stacktrace.

Comment: Look how attributes (like `data1`) are handled. Stacktrace first.

Comment: Hi All, I have edited my question added the code I am trying in Java.

Comment: At which line of the code, are you getting the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: I m getting this error at line "NodeList nlList = eElementRoute.getElementsByTagName("data1").item(0).getChildNodes();"

Comment: "data1" is not an *element*. So `getElementsByTagName("data1")` will return `null`. You need to get the *attributes* of "mainData".

Comment: [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140614/xml-parsing-with-child-not-value-parsing/12141225#12141225) @Deepu

Comment: Thank you all, I simple used Element.getAttribute("data1") as per your suggestions, it worked.

Comment: better be precise in your question, and make it as simple as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data1 is not an Element, but an attribute. Therefore when using the method getElementByTagName() then calling the method item() on it, without checking if the first returns anything would cause a NullPointerException.

Try getting the Attributes. For an example, check here:
http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/easy-dom-parsing-in-java/231002580

Comment: Thanks, I simple used Element.getAttribute("data1"), it worked.

Answer (score 2):

well ya, you are trying to fetch Element, and you are fetching attribute. So what I suggest is , try to clear Basic fundamentals and if you want to fetch element, then you must write like this

```
nodeobject.getElementsByTagName("Elementobject");
```

and as there is no tag, so that is giving you

```
NUll POINTER
```

and for attribute you have to go for `FOR loop` if attribute is there.

Comment: Thanks Krishna for your answer.

Comment: My pleasure Deepu :) anytime :)